# sort only the positive value and remain the negative value with it's index as it is of an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to sort the array in ascending order only for the positive value. 
For the negative value the index position will remain the same as it is.

If the array is : `int[] inputArray = {-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180}`.

The output should be like this - `int[] outputArray = {-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190}`.

But in my case the output 
is this - `int[] outputArray = {-1, 150, 170, 190, -1, -1, 160, 180}`.

Here is my code below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] inputArray = {-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180};
    int[] outputArray = sortByHeight(inputArray);

    for (int item : outputArray) {
        System.out.print(item + ", ");
    }
}

public static int[] sortByHeight(int[] inputArray) {
    for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<inputArray.length - 1; j++) {
            int temp = inputArray[j];
            if (temp >= 0) {
                if (inputArray[j] > inputArray[j+1] && inputArray[j+1] >= 0) {
                    inputArray[j] = inputArray[j+1];
                    inputArray[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second loop, for every `inputArray[j]` you need to find next element which is greater than 0 before comparing.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputArray = {-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180};
        int[] outputArray = sortByHeight(inputArray);

        for (int item : outputArray) {
            System.out.print(item + ", ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] sortByHeight(int[] inputArray) {
        for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<inputArray.length - 1; j++) {
                int temp = inputArray[j];
                if (temp >= 0) {
                    int k = j+1;
                    while(inputArray[k] < 0)
                       k++;
                    if (inputArray[j] > inputArray[k] && inputArray[k] >= 0) {
                        inputArray[j] = inputArray[k];
                        inputArray[k] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return inputArray;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for everybody's answer. But your whole work with the current array not cloning or uses any collection. that's why I am choosing this answer as accepted.

Comment: @SumonBappi If you don't want a new array with the result, but want the input array modified, why does your method have a return value? It should be `void`, similar to how [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) is `void`.

Comment: @Andreas you are right. I remove the return type in my program. thanks

Comment: @SumonBappi You prefer the slowest of the slow, a [Bubblesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) of all things? Well, it will get the job done.... Eventually.

Answer (score 7):

Try to:

1. Extract only the positive values
2. Sort them using `Collections.sort` (or `Array.sort`)
3. Go through the original array and replace the positive values by the ordered ones

Comment: (Yes, but I assume one would extract the values in something else than an array, like a simple linked list)

Comment: I don't think, that a `LinkedList` could be more efficient. I'd bet that using an `ArrayList` is faster. Using an array of the original size and sorting a subarray is IMHO fastest.

Answer (score 6):

You could try to sort yourself, or extract just the positive values and sort them, but here is an alternate version that **leaves input array unmodified** *(since returning new array from method would otherwise be unnecessary)*.

Code simply copies and sorts the input array first, then merges negative values from input array with positive values from sorted array. Since negative values were sorted first, there's no chance of overwriting sorted values being copies.

Code also doesn't box the values, as would otherwise be necessary for building a `List<Integer>` of positive values.

```
private static int[] sortByHeight(int[] inputArray) {
    int[] arr = inputArray.clone();
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length && arr[i] < 0)
        i++;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
        arr[j] = (inputArray[j] < 0 ? inputArray[j] : arr[i++]);
    return arr;
}
```

*Test*

```
int[] inputArray = {-1, 150, 190, 170, -2, -1, 160, 180};
int[] outputArray = sortByHeight(inputArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputArray));
```

*Output*

```
[-1, 150, 160, 170, -2, -1, 180, 190]
```

The re-use of `arr` as both the sorted array of all values, and the result array, works because positive value will only be copied *down*, or stay where they are.

To illustrate:

```
-1, 150, 190, 170,  -2,  -1, 160, 180   // Input array
 ↓                   ↓    ↓
 ↓                   ↓    ↓
 ↓                   ↓    ↓
-1, 150, 160, 170,  -2,  -1, 180, 190   // Result array
     ↑    ↑    └─────────┐    ↑    ↑
     ↑    └─────────┐    ↑    ↑    ↑
     └─────────┐    ↑    ↑    ↑    ↑
-2,  -1,  -1, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190   // Array after sorting
```

Comment: Much more efficient and simpler than any of the other approaches, and trivially adaptable to solve the OPs exact task. There is one possible improvement though: The last loop only has to loop while `i != j`.

Comment: I'd be more confident about the correctness if you used different negative values. Concerning the speed, it loses when most values are negative, But +1 for a good idea and implementation.

Comment: @maaartinus Well, with just a small change one can adapt it to favor more negative numbers: Manually copy the non-negative-values into the end of the new array, and only sort those. Keep track of where that sequence starts, and otherwise follow this algo.

Comment: @maaartinus Code is explicitly copying negative values from input array to same index in result array, so not sure why you lack confidence about the correctness of that matching the requirement *"For the negative value the index position will remain the same as it is"*. But, I've updated answer to show a `-2` value too.

Comment: It's not about lacking confidence, it's about improving the example. It was my very first idea when I looked at it: Anything what can go wrong, will go wrong, let's improve the test when it's simple enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Integer> positives = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i : inputArray) 
  if (i > 0) positives.add(i);
Collections.sort(positives);

int x = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < inputArray.length; y++)
  if (inputArray[y] > 0) inputArray[y] = positives.get(x++);
```

This extracts all the positive values from the input `int` array, sorts them, and replaces the positive values one by one.

Answer (score 3):

Turning what @jean-logeart said into code:

```
public static int[] sortByHeight(int[] inputArray) {
    // Extract only the positive values
    ArrayList<Integer> positiveValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int value: inputArray) {
        if (value > 0) positiveValues.add(value);
    }

    // Sort them using Collections.sort (or Array.sort)
    Collections.sort(positiveValues);

    // Go through the original array and replace the positive values by the ordered ones
    int positiveIndex = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < inputArray.length; index++) {
        if (inputArray[index] > 0) {
            inputArray[index] = positiveValues.get(positiveIndex);
            positiveIndex++;
        }
    }

    return inputArray;
}
```

Running with the main() supplied in the question produces:

```
-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190,
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a replacement in place like this:

```
 int[] inputArray = { -1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180 };

    Iterator<Integer> sorted = Arrays.stream(inputArray)
            .filter(x -> x > 0)
            .sorted()
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .iterator();

    IntStream.range(0, inputArray.length)
            .forEach(x -> {
                if (inputArray[x] > 0) {
                    inputArray[x] = sorted.next();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi Eugene! Yours is the clearest solution, IMO. However, I think there's place for improvement. There's no point in boxing the stream and collecting it to a list just to grab an iterator. Instead, grab a primitive iterator directly from the stream: `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt sorted = Arrays.stream(inputArray).filter(x -> x > 0).sorted().iterator();`. And as for the in-place replacement , you could use `Arrays.setAll`: `Arrays.setAll(inputArray, x -> inputArray[x] > 0 ? sorted.nextInt() : inputArray[x]);`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner honestly, I have just started digging into Spliterators, and at the moment I can't tell if that is going to be better then what I have in place - besides the boxing/un-boxing optimization; but thx for looking into this, it looks interesting.

Comment: are you saying that spliterators are inefficient or are somehow broken?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner by *far* no. It's just that spliterators might behave weird sometimes (from the numerous videos I've seen). again I can't really tell until I really dig deeper.

Comment: Ok, looking forward to hearing about your findings. Please let me know if you ask a question about that or write an article, etc. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void sortByHeight(int[] inputArray) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] > 0)
            list.add(inputArray[i]);
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] > 0){
            inputArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(list.get(j).toString());
        j++;}
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(inputArray[i]);
    }
}
```